# Как правильно сортировать в stream api данные из json?

Tags: java, json

У меня есть код, который должен спарсить данные из json файла и должен отсортировать его по возрасту(данном случае те, кто старше 18 лет), но он не работает!
что тут не так?
код:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    Person person = new Person();

    try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("/home/xxx/IdeaProjects/hw/src/people.json");
        person = gson.fromJson(fr, Person.class);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    personList.add(person);

    List<Person> adults = personList
            .stream()
            .filter(person1 -> person1.getAge() > 18)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(adults);
}
```

}

Comment: А почему у вас в `personList` всего один `Person` ?

Comment: @RomanDanilov а как должно быть тогда здесь:         person = gson.fromJson(fr, Person.class);
?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, вам нужно сделать что-то типа этого:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Main {

    private final static Gson GSON = new Gson();    
    private final static String FILE_NAME = "/home/xxx/IdeaProjects/hw/src/people.json";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE_NAME))) {
            final Person[] persons = GSON.fromJson(reader, Person[].class);
            List<Person> adults = Stream.of(persons)
                    .filter(person -> person.getAge() > 18)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(adults);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: если это не сработает, то добавляйте ваш джейсон в вопрос

Comment: Фильтр есть, сортировка не наблюдается

Comment: @ Sergey Mitrofanov формулировка вопроса говорит о том, что с высокой вероятностью нужен именно фильтр, потому что написано так : У меня есть код, который должен спарсить данные из json файла и должен отсортировать его по возрасту(данном случае те, кто старше 18 лет), посему , если нужна сортиовка, то, во-первых, это ,мягко говоря, несложно, во-вторых, можно спросить в комментариях, если самому разобраться не получается

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код только отбирает товарищей `filter`, но не сортирует их.

Для сортировки применяем `sorted()` в стриме или уже сортируем список после фильтрации.